# Adding a key on a density graph with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I want to add a key so that I'm able to know which color is which column in my data frame. I made this by `df.column_name.plot.density()` multiple times. I've seen other examples with the key but I haven't been able to locate the code that adds it in. 
[image: Density Plot]

Comment: `Wisconsin` is misspelled.

Comment: Haha thank you, I'll fix that

Answer (score 0):

In `matplotlib`, the display you're talking about is called a **legend**. I'm not sure if it's the same in `pandas`, but it's worth looking at!

Since your example didn't include enough code for me to try it out, I didn't.

Comment: The data I'm working with is on a csv file or else I'd include it too. But thank you! I'll look that up

Answer (score 0):

Don't plot the variables one by one. Use `df.plot.density()`. If you want to plot a subset of variables: `df.plot[var_list].density()`. If you want to plot them one by one for some reason you may need to use `label` argument in plot function and add a legend at the end.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size = (10,4)),
                  columns = ["Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4"])
df.plot.density()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I tried that and the graph came out as a y = 0 graph (a straight horizontal line).

Comment: I've added an example. Can you check if that works?

Comment: @curlsandcpsc It could be because you need to subset your dataframe as in `df.plot[var_list].density()`